# how to call flutter web function in html

Tags: html

hello i`m flutter web developer

here is my flutter code

```dart
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'dart:js_util';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;


 final html.IFrameElement _iframeElement = html.IFrameElement();
  Widget iframeWidget = HtmlElementView(
    key: UniqueKey(),
    viewType: 'PayPalButtons',
  );

@override
  void initState() {
    // ignore:undefined_prefixed_name
    setProperty(
        html.window, 'getAddress', js.allowInterop<Function>(getAddress));
    _iframeElement.height = '500';
    _iframeElement.width = '500';
    _iframeElement.src = 'web/pay_pal.html';
  }
```

i want flutter function here

```dart
Future<void> getAddress(String test) async {
    if (test != null && test != '') {
      print(test);
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<div id="paypal-button-container-P-1F9565844N640864EMRYDXIQ"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AXpoiKwxgqgpa8WqRBEmTPr6tUzQtkIc3izShEFUByMNwW9M_pQ4ND-VcB_i90bzSzcXZKV4Vr_hQzly&vault=true&intent=subscription" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            shape: 'rect',
            color: 'gold',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'subscribe'
        },
        createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
                /* Creates the subscription */
                plan_id: 'P-1F9565844N640864EMRYDXIQ'
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            window.getAddress(data.subscriptionID);
            alert(data.subscriptionID); // You can add optional success message for the subscriber here
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container-P-1F9565844N640864EMRYDXIQ'); // Renders the PayPal button
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

souce tree
--web
index.html
pay_pal.html
..

i meet errer here

```
TypeError: window.getAddress is not a function
web/pay_pal.html 21:20
```

i`m tryed all process

but i can`t call function

i must call function
because i can`t find call exit
how to call flutter function in html??

other project similar code can call function